# Uniqueness of the Helmholtz equation for bounded domains

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; \ |x| < \pi/2, \ |y| < \pi/2\}$. The problem
$$ \left \{\begin{array}{rcl}
- \Delta u - u & = & 0, \ \mbox {in} \ \Omega\\
u(x) & = & g(x), \ \mbox{on} \ \partial \Omega.
\end{array} \right.$$
has at most one solution.

**Approach idea:** As usual, I tried to call $w = v - u$, where $u$ and $v$ are classic and different solutions to the problem. Then we would have:
$$ \left \{\begin{array}{rcl}
- \Delta w & = & w, \ \mbox {in} \ \Omega\\
w & = & 0, \ \mbox{on} \ \partial \Omega.
\end{array} \right.$$
Thus, I tried to use the Poincaré inequality to reach some conclusion. But it was work in vain. Can you help me?

Comment: In general the solution may not be unique. It depends on the domain $\Omega$.

Comment: How did you use the Poincare inequality and why do you think this did not work?

Comment: In summary, when I use Poincaré inequality and Green identities, we come up with something like this: $\int_{\Omega} w^2 \leq \mbox{diam}(\Omega)\int_{\Omega} w^2$. In this case, since $\Omega$ is a rectangle, we have $\mbox{diam}(\Omega) = \sqrt{2}\pi$. So, I couldn't finish anything...